# перебор значений свойств объекта и вывод свойства значения выбранного свойства

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть селект в котором выведены свойства объекта, нужно что бы в зависимости от выбранного свойства выводилось его значение. Не знаю в чем проблема, возможно объект не правильно структурирован, объекты только недавно начал изучать... Вот код:

```js
var ah = {
  40: 8,
  45: 10,
  50: 11,
  55: 12,
  60: 14,
  65: 15,
  70: 16,
  75: 16,
  85: 17,
  90: 18,
  95: 19,
  100: 20,
  110: 21,
  120: 25,
  132: 30,
  140: 32,
  190: 42,
  200: 44,
  210: 46,
  220: 48,
  230: 50,

}


Object.keys(ah).forEach((item) => {
  $('#select-ah').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
  $('#select-ah').change(function() {
    var op = $(this).val();
    if (op) {
      $('#res1').html('');
      var op1 = ah[op];
      Object.keys(op1).forEach(function(item) {
        $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").attr("value", item).text(item));
      });
    } else {
      $('#res1').html('<span>Результат</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-ah">
  <option>Выберите емкость (A/ч)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="block__val" style="display:flex;justify-content: center;width:35%;">
  <span class="btn-btn1" id="minus">-</span>
  <input type="text" value="1" style="text-align: center;border-radius: 0px;" id="val1">
  <span class="btn-btn1" id="plus">+</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="price-itog">
  <p style="margin-top: 47px; color:#2E0648;">Стоимость: <span id="res1"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ah = {
  40: 8,
  45: 10,
  50: 11,
  55: 12,
  60: 14,
  65: 15,
  70: 16,
  75: 16,
  85: 17,
  90: 18,
  95: 19,
  100: 20,
  110: 21,
  120: 25,
  132: 30,
  140: 32,
  190: 42,
  200: 44,
  210: 46,
  220: 48,
  230: 50,

}

$(document).ready(function() {

function calcTotal() {
    $('#res1').html('');
    var op = $("#select-ah").val();
    var op1 = +ah[op];
    var v = +$("#val1").val();
    var total = op1 * v;
    //console.log(op, op1, v, total);
    if (!isNaN(total)) {
      $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").text(total));
    } else {
      $('#res1').html('<span>Результат</span>');
    }
}

  $('#minus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = +$input.val();
    if (isNaN(count))
      count = 0;
    count--;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
  });
  $('#plus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = +$input.val();
    if (isNaN(count))
      count = 0;
    count++;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
  });
  
  Object.keys(ah).forEach((item) => {
    $('#select-ah').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
  });
  
  $('#select-ah').change(calcTotal);
  $(".block__val input").change(calcTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-ah">
  <option>Выберите емкость (A/ч)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="block__val" style="display:flex;justify-content: center;width:35%;">
  <span class="btn-btn1" id="minus">-</span>
  <input type="text" value="1" style="text-align: center;border-radius: 0px;" id="val1">
  <span class="btn-btn1" id="plus">+</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="price-itog">
  <p style="margin-top: 47px; color:#2E0648;">Стоимость: <span id="res1"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, постоянно помогаете... В данном случае я пропустил $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").text(op1)); ?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Да. И цикл `Object.keys(op1).forEach` там не к месту.

Comment: Еще нужно подтянуть значение из количества и умножить на полученное значение в #res1 и записать в него же

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Кроме того, учтите, что `$("select").val()` возвращает текст выбранного элемента `option`, если у этого элемента нет атрибута `value`.

Comment: var text = $('#val1');
      var op2 = text.innerHTML;
      $('#res1').append($("<span></span>").text(op1*40*op2));

Comment: Почему то так если делаю выдает NaN

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Потому что у обертки jQuery нет свойства `innerHTML`: `var op2 =  text.val();`

Comment: Точно, спасибо еще раз. Сейчас все работает за исключением нажатия на прибавление кнопок - и +, сейчас при клике по ним значение op2 не меняется сразу а меняется только при событие onchnge, если перенести это все в функцию прибавления значения то пропадет видимость переменной?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Как раз правильно - перенести в функцию. Только `var op = $(this).val();` надо будет изменить на `var op = $("#select-ah").val();`.

Comment: Что то не срабатывает... Я Ваш код поправлю добавлю полный листинг, если не сложно посмотрите

Comment: @ilyaaa521 добавил

Comment: Добрый день, можете еще посмотреть? Добавляю кнопку сброса, правильно ли делаю?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 куда смотреть?

Comment: Поправил Ваш ответ, #reset1 - сама кнопка сброса

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Вы пробовали запускать этот код? В нем несколько синтаксических и логических ошибок.

Comment: Пробовал,просто не совсем понятно как сделать, или может через clear, логика такая, создать переменную которая умножает на 0, то есть сбрасывает калькулятор, потом при клике возвратил эту переменную, но не могу понять что не так

Comment: @ilyaaa521 нет, неправильно. Задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Задал новый вопрос